# Option to insert userform in Excel VBA is not displayed in Mac version

Tags: excel, vba, macos, userform

I wanted to create a Userform in the Visual Basic editor but that option seems not available (see screenshot). 
How can I change that?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can't in the Mac version of Excel 2016 ff.
If you need to change or add a userform you will need to do it in Mac Excel 2011 or a Windows version.

Also see
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2016-macexcel/how-to-edit-a-user-form-in-excel-2016-vba/f34fb31f-504d-4844-9831-a4500a5523c5

Also there is a user voice vote to add this feature to the mac version:
https://excel.uservoice.com/forums/304933-excel-for-mac/suggestions/10355043-enable-vba-support-for-creating-and-editing-userfo

It is not implemented yet.
Also see here: [Userform with Excel 2018 for MacOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50399661/userform-with-excel-2018-for-macos)